# Need help accomplishing a join

Tags: sql, join

Current SELECT query

```
SELECT a.*, ROUND(((a.avg-b.avg)/b.avg)*100,2) pct_change
FROM
  ( 
     SELECT x.*, COUNT(*) rank
     FROM blavg x 
         JOIN blavg y 
             ON y.bline_id = x.bline_id 
            AND y.id >= x.id 
     GROUP BY x.id
) a
JOIN
( 
     SELECT x.*, COUNT(*) rank
     FROM blavg x 
         JOIN blavg y 
             ON y.bline_id = x.bline_id 
            AND y.id >= x.id 
     GROUP BY x.id
 ) b
     ON b.bline_id = a.bline_id
     AND b.rank = a.rank+1
WHERE a.rank = 1;
```

I would like to also

```
SELECT bl_id, bline FROM bl
bl.bl_id = blavg.bline_id
```

I've tried

```
SELECT bl_id, bline 
FROM bl bl 
    LEFT JOIN ON bl.bl_id = blavg.bline_id
```

but not sure if I had the right syntax, and I wasn't sure where to add the `ON` and where the parens () went.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are doing some sort of query to retrieve rows twice by twice and doing some maths.
Luckily enough, your query already return the `bline_id` you need to link to your `bl` table.

So you just need one more joint on your results to retrieve the `bl.bline` field you need :

```
SELECT bl.bline, a.*, ROUND(((a.avg-b.avg)/b.avg)*100,2) pct_change
FROM
  ( 
     SELECT x.*, COUNT(*) rank
     FROM blavg x 
         JOIN blavg y 
             ON y.bline_id = x.bline_id 
            AND y.id >= x.id 
     GROUP BY x.id
) a
JOIN
( 
     SELECT x.*, COUNT(*) rank
     FROM blavg x 
         JOIN blavg y 
             ON y.bline_id = x.bline_id 
            AND y.id >= x.id 
     GROUP BY x.id
 ) b
     ON b.bline_id = a.bline_id
     AND b.rank = a.rank+1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN bl
         ON bl.bl_id = a.bline_id
WHERE a.rank = 1;
```

Comment: @ScorpiO - Well that seems almost too obvious! It worked perfectly thank you so much!!